# Set image styling "height:1%" sometimes work, sometimes doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

Here is the snippet ([also on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLnx66L2/3/)):

```html
<div>
  start
  <img src="http://www.baidu.com/img/bdlogo.png" style="border: 1px solid; height:1%;">
  end
</div>
```

I set the inline style of `img` to `height:1%` and expect to see it become much smaller, however, its size doesn't change at all, at least not changed in the Demo above or JsFiddle.

Weirdly, **when I copy EXACTLY the same code and save it into an HTML file,it works**, which can be viewed [AT HERE](http://compbio.tongji.edu.cn/~sunhf/test.htm)

Does anyone have ideas about why `height:1%` works when the snippet is saved as an HTML file but doesn't work when pasted into an online editor?

(It seems the cause of different is the `doctype`, but I was wondering what standard will be used when `doctype` is not specified at all and `div` element wrapped in neither `<html>` nor `<body>`. As I understand, set the `img`'s height inside a block element should not take effect at all. )

Comment: What `doctype` are you using in the html file? It is likely the cause of the difference.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I didn't assign `doctype` at all. The outermost element is the `div`, wrapped in neither `<html>`  nor `<body>`

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I was curious  what standard will be used when doctype is not specified at all, because as I understand, setting the img's height inside a block element should not take effect at all..

Comment: That's probably the cause. The browser doesn't know how to render the page properly. Try adding the html5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Height in percent is dependent on the height of the parent element so you have to set a height on the div in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

using percent heights is tricky-- because it needs to be a percentage of something. typically the outer div "wrapper" would define the total height, and the inner div would be a percentage of this. browsers handle this slightly differently when no specific height is defined anywhere. width is different and is most always simply the width client window, but height has two possiblities-- the height of the entire site or the height of the viewable area.

in css3 you can use vh is indicated view height so use height = '1vh' for 1% of viewable area otherwise you must give the outer div a defined height so the inner div can work.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a parent div with Specified height (in px or % or etc) for your image .like this:

```
  <div style="height:100px;width:100%">
    start
    <img src="http://www.baidu.com/img/bdlogo.png" style="border: 1px solid; height:10%;">
    end
  </div>
```

In this way, you can be sure about this code work in every browsers.